# Twitter login in android application and post a tweet for diffrent users

Tags: android

I have made a Consumer key and a Consumer secret from my twitter account and I have post a tweet to twitter in my account and this works fine. My application is to login from different user in twitter and post their tweet. Is this possible. If it is then how will you handle the case of Consumer key and Consumer secret for different users. Please provide me if any valid link for this scenario.

Comment: i have solve this issue on stack overflow .. please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134629/in-android-how-directly-post-tweet-to-following-users-of-a-authenticate-user-in This Link answer check out!
i hope this link can help u !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumer key and Consumer secret are used for verifying apps not for users. So every user will use the same Consumer key and Consumer secret to login your twitter app.

You can reference some android twitter wrapper like [twiiter-android-sdk](https://github.com/grantland/twitter-android-sdk)