# How to get Twitter Friends List?

Tags: android

How to get Twitter friends  list for new Twitter API.I tried by using twitter.getFollowersList(String, long) method but I can't find how to use it.Help me how to solve it..?

Regards

Comment: Take a look here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids for documentation.

Comment: I've added one more link for the implementation, just have look

Comment: Hey my problem solved .can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134629/in-android-how-directly-post-tweet-to-following-users-of-a-authenticate-user-in for solving same type of problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this library, you can easily achieve that
https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/FriendsAndFollowers/GetFriendsByID/

and you need set authorization before you connect. just go through this Documentation
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

and this post will help you how to implement to get the friendlist go to this list read those codes
[In Android -How directly post tweet to following users of a authenticate user in android without open Tweet dialog (Message Dialog box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134629/in-android-how-directly-post-tweet-to-following-users-of-a-authenticate-user-in)